# Text color distorts on first time after chrome browser cache clearing

Tags: google-chrome, caching, text, colors, browser-cache

Text color distorts on first time load after chrome browser cache clearing (or in incognito mode). While it is working fine with the normal chrome window. Please view attached image.[image: Issue IMage]

After loading the same page second time, it is working fine. It only distorts the text color on first time.

Comment: Does it fix itself after a few seconds, or does it stay distorted until refreshing the page?

Comment: @SamWillis it stays distorted until refreshing the page